# textview background not changing after clicking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wrote a code about changing the TextView background after clicking the text, however the background color did not change but the other TextView background color change. I understand recyclerview is to reuse the view, so i set `notifyItemchanged()` to avoid it to reset the view.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<String> innertext;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> items,Context context){
        this.innertext = items;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.background_color, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String s = innertext.get(position);
        holder.t1.setText(s);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return innertext.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView t1;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            t1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();

            t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#455A64"));
            notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }

    }
}
```

if you need more code from me please let me know.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped u

Answer (score 2):

This is not a tried code but it will explain the logic to you:-

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private List<String> innertext;
private Context mContext;
private boolean[] checked={false};

public MyAdapter(List<String> items, Context context) {
    this.innertext = items;
    this.mContext = context;
    checked = new boolean[items.size()];
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.background_color, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String s = innertext.get(position);
    ((MyViewHolder)holder).t1.setText(s);
    if(checked[position]){
        ((MyViewHolder)holder).t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#455A64"));
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return innertext.size();
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView t1;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        t1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        checked[pos] = true;
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

}
```

}

basically you have to store the position which has been clicked in a boolean array and then set color in onbindview by checking if it has been clicked, as recyclerview doesnt work the way u think, it recycle Views

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#455A64"));
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

copy & paste below code in method `onBindViewHolder`

`holder.t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         t1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, Color.parseColor("#455A64")););
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @ankitagrawal. I think that's the correct solution!

This is my answer. 
- The same logic but different approach. Hope i did this right because i'm not using AS or eclipse. I just modified @ankitagrawal's answer. Thanks :)

**http://pastebin.com/C7fqhhUa**

Comment: fran your code is right, i basically use the same approach in my apps but since the OP didnt use any model i used boolean array example, to make him understand the logic implementation he can do as per liking